# Use groupby in dataframe to perform data filtering and element-wise subtraction

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe composed by the following table:

```
A   B  C  D 
A1  5  3   4
A1  8  1   0 
A2  1  1   0 
A2  1  9   1
A2  1  3   1 
A3  0  4   7
...
```

I need to group the data according to the 'A' label, then check whether the sum of the 'B' column for each label is larger than 10. If it is larger than 10 then perform an operation that involves subtracting 'C' and 'D'. Finally, I need to drop all rows that identify those 'A' labels for which the condition on the sum is not larger than 10. I am trying to use the `groupby` method, but I am not sure this is the right way to go. So far I have grouped everything with `df.groupby('A')['B'].sum()` and get a list of sums per grouped label in order to check the aforementioned condition on the 10 elements. But then how to apply the subtraction between columns C and D and also drop the irrelevant rows?

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum` for new `Series` filled by aggregate values and filter rows greater like `10` in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and then subtract columns:

```
df = df[df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum').gt(10)].copy()
df['E'] = df['C'].sub(df['D'])
print (df)
    A  B  C  D  E
0  A1  5  3  4 -1
1  A1  8  1  0  1
```

Similar idea if need `sum` column:

```
df['sum'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('sum')
df['E'] = df['C'].sub(df['D'])
df = df[df['sum'].gt(10)].copy()
print (df)
    A  B  C  D  sum  E
0  A1  5  3  4   13 -1
1  A1  8  1  0   13  1
```